# Git, view multiple branches in the same repository

Tags: git

Here is our work process:

1. Developers are cloning from a central repository.
2. Dev A is locally working on bug fix A, branch `bug_a`, push branch `bug_a` to central repository.
3. Dev B is locally working on bug fix B, branch `bug_b`, push branch `bug_b` to central repository.
4. When the work is finished the branches are merged to a `develop` branch.

Lets assume (for simplicity) that both branches do not touch common files. Our requirement is that in the end exactly can be reconstructed which files and code is changed with
`bug_a`. The same for `bug_b`. So the commit for the merge of `bug_a` in `develop` shows exact the changes done for this bug A solution.

Now the question arises: I am working on `bug_a` and I want to see the changes of `bug_b` in my repository.

I know I can pull the changes of `bug_b` in my `bug_a` branch BUT now my requirement is not
fulfilled because at the final merge/commit in `develop` I see also the changes of `bug_b`
and I cannot reconstruct the exact changes done for solving bug A.

My question is there a command or procedure in Git where the changes made in other branches
are visible in the local working branch? Just like a 'view' in clearcase e.g.

```
master
develop
bug_b
*bug_a
```

Answer (score 2):

To abuse some terminology, each git repo is itself a lot like a clearcase private view: you can't see the other guy's directly.  (But there's a shortcut I will mention in a bit.)

Fortunately, you can see his indirectly, because you two have a third, shared repo.  He pushes to the shared repo, then you `fetch` (don't `pull` yet because that complicates the answer) from the shared repo.  Now you can see what he did, because `fetch` grabs (by default anyway) everything.

Here's where git is very different from clearcase, though: you "see what he did" by asking git to extract it to somewhere visible.  It won't "just show up", you have to tell it "let me see".

You can see it by doing one or more of the following:

- asking git (or a GUI) to show diffs
- asking git to check out a different branch into the current work tree (there is obvious potential for collisions here)
- asking git to check out the contents of one or more particular files from a particular branch, into the current work tree
- asking git to check out a different branch into a *different* (perhaps new) work tree

All of these need some understanding of how to specify particular revisions (by "branch name" or by commit-ID or whatever).  Here's two important things to keep in mind:

- When you clone and fetch, git creates branches with names like `remotes/origin/master` and `remotes/origin/bug_b`.
- When you work locally in your repo, git creates branches with names like `master` and `bug_a`.

So, to view changes that have been `fetch`ed into `remotes/origin/bug_b`, use:

```
git log remotes/origin/bug_b
```

Note that you need not have your own branch named `bug_b`, much less do any merge-ing or pull-ing or whatever.  Just name the remote branch, when you only want to look.  You only need your own branch name if you're going to do your own work on a `bug_b` branch.

Here's a deeper bit that you don't need to understand yet, but you should come back to it now and then: a branch name like `remotes/origin/bug_b` is really just a symbolic way to name one of those big git SHA1 values like `ae0af6d748b98716f0f72e428728345b828c4067`.  What git does when you `fetch` is to obtain all the new files and trees and such, and all the commits with those big hairy IDs, and stuff all of them into *your* repository; then update the `remotes/x/y` labels to point to the "tips" of each "remote branch".  Your repo has everything everyone has ever done, right there at your fingertips if needed.  (Sometimes that turns out to "too much" so there are ways of limiting how much you actually have, but "everything" is the default, and is the way to think about it.)  (In clearcase-ish terms, you have a complete copy of every VOB.  Fortunately git is way more space- and time-efficient than clearcase.)

When you do a `git pull` you're really doing two things: a `git fetch`—this is what pulls changes over—and then (normally) a `git merge`.  The merge combines "work someone else did" with "work you did".  You don't want that when you're fetching the changes Bob did for `bug_b` while working on your own `bug_a` branch.

(Optionally, you can tell git to make `git pull` mean `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  But you don't want that either.  Just stick with `git fetch`.)

Now, for that shortcut: if you `git clone` the original shared repo, then you have to wait for Bob to `git push` his `bug_b` changes back to the shared repo, before you can see them.  But, if Bob grants you read access (via ssh or whatever) to his private repo, you can add Bob's repo as an alternate "remote".  Instead of `remotes/origin/bug_b` you can name this remote `remotes/bob/` for instance, and refer to `remotes/bob/bug_b`.  You can fetch those with `git remote update bob`.  Don't bother with all this unless you can coordinate with Bob, though.  The single shared repo to which you both `push` is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have branch `A` checked out, and you want to view changes made in branch `B`.  Then you can see the changes made in `B` with

```
git log --patch B
```

which will show you all the commits made in `B`, along with the diff of the changes that each commit introduces.  You can read more about using `git log` at [the Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

If you don't have the latest changes made in `B` from your remote/central repo in your local repo, you can [`git fetch <remote repo>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) those changes into your local repo, without merging those changes into `A`.  Then you can view those changes with

```
git log --patch remoteRepo/B
```

A lot of Git guis have visual diff viewers that you can use as well, to view any branch that you want.